# Using a form select inside a CSS dropdown (megamenu) fails in IE7—workarounds?

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer-7, hover

We are building a css drop down megamenu for a website that will include an HTML form with selects. In IE7, when you click on a select, it's pop-up menu opens up (naturally). Then when you mouseover the menu to select an item, it appears as though the focus is taken away from the page, the containing div/li loses :hover, and the whole thing closes before you can select an option.

Preview in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q284w/

The JSFiddle above has the offending code in "Menu 1" ... and, yes, I'm using a table to get a full-height, vertically-centered, 3-column layout in that menu. It's in the original code, so I put it in here; I don't think it's part of the problem, but you never know with IE.

This, of course, works in every other browser I can test including IE8+.

Any ideas on a workaround? Perhaps JavaScript can save the day?

Comment: were you ever able to come up with a solution for this, I find myself having the same problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately there is no easy answer for this (that I found). You simply have to work around it using JavaScript, and it's a pain. This gist of it is as follows:

1. Create a special class that mimics the :hover state. You will use this to "hold" the menu open.
2. Create a function that adds this class to the appropriate menu item and attach to onClick of the dropdown.
3. In another function, remove the class and attach that to onChange of the dropdown (the dropdown closes).